# Windows 10 was removed while installing Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 16.04

I installed ubuntu 16.04 recently. They asked me to install beside windows and I chose that option but still windows was removed after the installation. The windows is not being shown in the boot menu and its partitions are being shown in the ubuntu. Can anybody explain to me why this happened ? Have I lost my windows forever ?

The output for the command sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL was as follows :

```
NAME   FSTYPE   SIZE MOUNTPOINT                    LABEL
sda           698.7G                               
├─sda1 ntfs     200M /media/shrey/5C0E9CC30E9C979A 
├─sda2 ntfs   574.7G /media/shrey/5EDE9E79DE9E48E3 
├─sda3            1K                               
├─sda4 ntfs    14.8G                               LENOVO_PART
├─sda5 ntfs      29G /media/shrey/LENOVO           LENOVO
├─sda6 ext4    76.1G /                             
└─sda7 swap     3.9G [SWAP]                        
sr0            1024M
```

Comment: I don't think your Windows installation is removed. Can you please post the output of commant `sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL`? This will list disks and disk partitions.

Comment: It's hard to understand the output in comment, can you please update your question adding output of the command?

Comment: The 574.7G is my windows partition. But how do I open windows ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try doing

```
sudo update-grub
```

in a terminal?

Then reboot and if Windows is not corrupted and GRUB detects it then Windows should appear in the boot menu.

Comment: It worked !!! :)

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 `ntfs` type partitions on your disk, so you probably didn't lose your Windows installation, you just can't boot into Windows since Grub (the bootloader) couldn't manage to find it somehow.

In order to try to make Grub find Windows, you can try following:

1. Make sure `os-prober` package is installed:

   `$ sudo apt-get install os-prober`
2. Make grub re-create its configuration:

   `$ grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`

If this also doesn't work, you can post contents of your grub config file `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` and someone can help you add Windows to the menu manually.